# How to show Picasa album gallery in Android

Tags: android, picasa

I would like to show Picasa images in my Android app. 
I've read about some incompabilities with PicasaWebService so i need a way to login and get images list to show.

Has anyone found some good library/example?

Answer (score 1):

If anyones looking for an answer.

Android sample using Picasa web album API. Sample uses OAuth for login, creates and updates albums as well as uploading of photos to Picasa web album:

http://gdata-java-client.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.2.1-alpha/sample/picasa/picasa-atom-android-sample/instructions.html